# Java create objects of generic type with unknown in compilation type parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection, introspection

I have generic class :

```
class Field<T> { }
```

And some other class (whose type I know only at runtime) with many get methods for example :

```
   class A{
      public Date getDate();
      public String getName();
      public Integer getNumber();
   }
```

I want to create instances of class `Field` for all get methods, with `T` equals to return type of these `get` methods. For this example `Field<Date>`, `Field<String>`, `Field<Integer>`.

Can anybody help?

Comment: If you are going to do this via reflection, and at runtime, the generic type does not matter at all. You may just as well do it without the generic parameter.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Write a complete code example, even if it doesn't compile, that illustrates what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Reflection is not adapted to this use case. Consider using Introspection which directly expose methods to obtain the getters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use reflection typically for things that you only know at run-time. Generics information is erased at compile-time. So, while there are cases where you can mix the two, it is not common.

> I want to create instances of class Field for all get methods, with T equals to return type of these get methods. For this example Field, Field, Field.

To answer your question literally:

```
Field<Date> dateField = new Field<Date>();
Field<String> nameField = new Field<String>();
Field<Integer> numberField = new Field<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can create generic types of Field in this case, since generics are checked at compile time, while you are only able to get (via reflection) the return types of the declared methods of class A at runtime.

Comment: the only way to make a list for unknown classes is List<?> but this won't help relly much.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the getters, consider using introspection rather than reflection : it is intended for this purpose!

Here is a code to automatically obtain the getters. Beware, you also get "getClass()" getter!

```
for(PropertyDescriptor descriptor :Introspector.getBeanInfo(A.class).getPropertyDescriptors()){
  System.out.println("Getter method :" + descriptor.getReadMethod());
  System.out.println("Return type : " + descriptor.getReadMethod().getReturnType());
  Class<?> c=descriptor.getReadMethod().getReturnType();
}
```

}

Output :

```
Getter method :public final native java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()
Return type : class java.lang.Class
Getter method :public java.util.Date A.getDate()
Return type : class java.util.Date
Getter method :public java.lang.String A.getName()
Return type : class java.lang.String
Getter method :public java.lang.Integer A.getNumber()
Return type : class java.lang.Integer
```

Then, you can easily create a Field for each of those getters. For the generic type, it does not really make sense at runtime but it is still possible to use this in a code generator...

Comment: @trognanders check the library size then consider if it's worth to comment "Or use Commons Beanutils." under every answer

Comment: @trognanders, no need to get a time machine you can check the size in Maven and it's the almost same size with the latest update 200kb+

Comment: More sincerely, some things are best left in libraries. Correct functionality is vastly more important than jar size. Is there some platform where a megabyte matters still running a jvm?